# MySQL MyISAM fulltext search - how to add '#' as a word character for utf8 charset?

Tags: mysql, myisam, full-text-search

I am using MyISAM full text search. The table columns are having charset "utf8" and "utf8_general_ci" as collation.

Now I want to implement #HashTag system, so that if I search for "#HashTag", only rows that contain "#HashTag" show up. Not rows that just contains "HashTag".

According to the comment in [this MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html), its easy to do it for non-multibyte charsets, that is charsets with fixed-width encoding.

But I could not find a good reference for how to do it for utf8 charset. Has anyone done this for utf8 charset columns? If yes, could you list the exact steps?

Also, I want to avoid recompiling MySQL if possible.

Comment: very old question but I guess I need to modify MySQL files and recompile it? Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, but would it not be a good idea to parse out the hash tags during input time using a regular expression, and store them in a separate column? Might be easier (and faster) than bending mySQL into accepting `#` as a search character.

Comment: That's an option of course and probably faster too. But I don't know which is easier. I am looking for an easy solution now.